# Rendering Problems Exception raised during rendering in API Level 24

Tags: android, android-studio, layout

I have recently updated my API Level now its 24 and I noticed my layout previews weren't working, if I change API level 24 to 23 it works but on 24 its not working. anyone please help me.

Error:

> Rendering Problems Exception raised during rendering: 
> com/android/util/PropertiesMap**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you've changed the API lvl this way.
This only changes the API lvl that Android Studio uses to render a preview, not the actual API lvl used in building your project. That means what you did here won't affect the actual build. So, don't worry about it, and there is nothing you can really do about it.

To actually change the API lvl, change the **build.gradle** file.

[image: img]